# How to make textarea fill the width of its parent width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

Given that we don't know the div's width beforehand?

My idea: Calculate the div 's width with JS, find a way to convert it to cols and the apply the css to the textarea onthe fly. But perhaps there 's no need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`<textarea style="width:100%">`* will work in most cases.

If it doesn't, please provide more information!

<sub>* Note: for some reason, it will need the `cols` and `rows` attributes to validate. But setting a width or a height will override them, so put any value you want.</sub>

Comment: +1 I never realized that you need those attributes in order to make `width:100%` work. I used some other work around to automatically resize the textarea if its parent container is resized but now it is so much easier :) Thank you!

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think `cols` and `rows` are required to make the `width:100%` work... `cols` and `rows` are required attributes of a `textarea` HTML element, which considered invalid without them, i.e. an HTML validator will complain. The `width:100%` working the way you expect, is a function of the browser. This did not work for older browsers.

Answer (score 5):

I advise `flex` over `width: 100%`, as `100%` often does not account for borders, causing horizontal scrolls to appear.

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <textarea style="flex: 1"></textarea>
</div>
```